# Send ZeroMQ messages without sleep()

Tags: c++, zeromq

I have this ZeroMQ message sending code in my C application

```
void *socket= zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_DEALER);
// ...
zmq_msg_t zmsg;
zmq_msg_init_size (&zmsg, msg_size);
memcpy(zmq_msg_data (&zmsg), content, msg_size);
zmq_msg_send (&zmsg, socket, 0);
zmq_msg_close(&zmsg); 
sleep (1);
```

which actually works, but I dont like the fact that I have to call sleep(1) to flush out messages. If I leave it away no messages arrive at the server. Is there any other possibility to "flush" out the messages on the socket without calling sleep? I use ZeroMQ v3.2.2.

Thank you very much!

EDIT: This behaviour seems to occur only in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always make sure you close the socket and terminate the context.  `zmq_term()` will not return until there are no messages that have not been sent.  You can set LINGER on the socket to give an upper bound for how long it will wait before discarding messages.  The default behavior is to wait forever.

```
void *socket= zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_DEALER);
// ...
zmq_msg_t zmsg;
zmq_msg_init_size (&zmsg, msg_size);
memcpy(zmq_msg_data (&zmsg), content, msg_size);
zmq_msg_send (&zmsg, socket, 0);
zmq_msg_close(&zmsg);
zmq_close(socket);
zmq_term(context); // this will block until the message is actually sent
```

Comment: You are right. But I do not want to close the socket. In debug mode when sending messages, messages are not sent immediately how it seems, but when zmq "has time for it" to do. However, when debugging this behaviour can be really annoying since messages simply are not sent if not calling sleep. That is how I experienced it so far, maybe I miss something.

Comment: sending messages is async, that's much of why zmq is fast.  `zmq_msg_send` only hands a pointer off to the IO thread, which handles all of the actual sending and receiving.  If you terminate the process immediately after send without proper cleanup, essentially you are giving the thread a task, and then killing it before it gets a chance to do anything about it. Sleep does *not* guarantee that the message is sent, it only increases the probability.  zmq_term (with no LINGER set) will guarantee 100% that the message was sent.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `ZMQ_LINGER` socket option to 0, then closing the socket after you close the msg.

```
zmq_setsockopt(socket, ZMQ_LINGER, 0, sizeof(int));
...
zmq_close(socket);
```

Comment: I do not close the zmq socket all the time.